# How to merge local database server into a localhost service?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I've been recently learning how databases work and how to write a service that can operate the database. So the situation is following:
I have a MySQL database ran on a localhost server (XAMPP). Accessing the database is simple: `localhost:3036/my_database`.

In addition to that, I wrote a Java Spring service (actually just copied the sample from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mysql.git) that is supposed to be an interface accepting curl requests and based on them to operate the database. So far so good. Everything works. The problem is that this service also runs on a localhost address: `localhost:8080`.

I would like to implement the MySQL server into my Spring service so that I can just run this service and the database will run and be hosted on the same port. The data is supposed to be available only through this service so I don't want an additional independent MySQL server to be running on a different localhost port.
At the end of the day, I would like to generate an executable jar file that when ran provides me the service on a localhost address and deals with locally stored database seamlessly.

Edit:
I wouldn't like my database to be independent form the service. I don't want to take care of running it and connecting to the service. What I'm searching for is sommething like @jr593 mentioned in the answers below, **an embedded database**. But is it possible for such databases to save the data locally on the device that the service is running beetwen service runs?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you cannot have 2 services listening on the same port

Comment: XAMPP has mariadb and that normally runs on port 3306! _Not quite sure what you mean by_  ___Accessing the database is simple: localhost:3036/my_database___ Did you install something other than `phpMyAdmin` that runs on port 3036 and does something like `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: Well, you can run an embedded database inside your spring app, but you will still need to persist the data somehow, otherwise it will be lost between runs.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you really want to achieve. MySQL is a network server. Each client connects via the configured port. Your Spring application is a web application and it is not possible to use the same port. In a production environment the database port is usually blocked and no external direct access to the database port is permitted. Clients can only connect to the webapplication port.

Comment: I think an embedded database inside a spring app is the solution I was looking for. Thank you @jr593. An all of you as well for your comments.

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to build an executable jar and run it as a part of other application? Let's say inside of a Android Studio project? Something like: now run the service (a jar file) and communicate with it. So that the service is running on an android device on a local network. An app (where you give data that needs to be stored on the database) on the device will comunicate through it with the database and eventually I can connect to this service from a different device on lan if I need to.

Comment: You should create a new question for this (but be sure to check whether your question is on-topic). The term "executable JAR" doesn't make sense for Android. And why do you want to run a network service on a Android device?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few solution for this.

1. Change port for java app. It it's Spring Boot you could check property server.port and set it to e.g 8081.
2. You can chcek what is working on XAMPP on port 8080 and shoud down it (it could be apache or something else)
3. You don't need XAMPP to have MySQL on local host. You can stop/remove xampp and install standalone MySql, so you will take only port 3036 and nat 8080 and 3036.
4. You could use Docker with MySql image instead of XAMPP.